# Using Variables on the field

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I am trying to make a series of equations run when a button is clicked and then display line in a rich text box.

```
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
    MessageBox.Show("Number of Estimates:$" & vbCrLf & "Grand Total of Estimates:$" & vbCrLf & "Average of Estimates:$")
    Estimates = +1
    SummaryRichTextBox.Text = "Carpet Waste in Sq. Yards =" & vbCrLf & "Underlay Waste in Sq. Yards=" _
& vbCrLf & "TackStrip Waste in Ft. =" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "Number of Estimates =" _
& vbCrLf & "Accumulated Grand Total of Estimates ="
End Sub
```

This displays the sentence part ok but I was just wondering how I can get it to insert the value of a label after the =

```
ex.
Label1= 10
Carpet Waste in Sq. Yards = (label1 value here)
```

I am working on my second program ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the `Text` property of the label:

```
"Carpet Waste in Sq. Yards = " &  label1.Text
```